# Hide div class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

Hello I have a sign up form which is visible and I am trying to hide it when the page loads. So what I did was to put the whole form in a div class named "signup" and then hide it with a script code.

UPDATE: 
html

```
<script>
  document.write('<div class="js">');
  </script>

<span class="button">Sign In</span>
<div id="signup">
<div class="modal-bg">
<div id="modal">
    <span>Sign In<a href="#close" id="close">&#215;</a></span>
    <form>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <a id="forgot-link" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
        <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  document.write('</div>');
  </script>
```

My JS code (without hide function):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
          $('#modal').css('display','block');
          $('.modal-bg').fadeIn();
    });

        $('#close,.modal-bg').click(function(){
              $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();     
              $('#modal').fadeOut();
          return false;
        });
```

Even though the hide/appear seems to work the form goes hidden if I click on it. This is a problem as no one can sign up if they can't type/click on the form. 
(ISSUE FIXED)

here is the codepen (live version): http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/WbgrNK

Comment: If you wanted to do this on load, why not do it with CSS? .signup { display: none; }

Comment: @LShetty, one reason not to do that is if you had js disabled, the form would never be displayed

Comment: Js is enabled as if I remove the any hide code then the form appears on page load and it does close if I click on the close button

Comment: .signup { display: none; } - I did that already before asking here it doesn't work either.

Comment: now it's at the end of the body but I've tried on "head"  too. nothing seems to work. My form keeps being visible on page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the signup div at all - I think it complicates things.  Just start your modal background hidden so before your button click code add this:

```
$('.modal-bg').css('display','none');
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxJrRq)

**Update**

to stop your form showing up whilst your page loads I would add a js div:

after your body opening tag:

```
<script>
   document.write('<div class="js">');
</script>
```

before your body closing tag:

```
<script>
   document.write('</div>');
</script>
```

This allows you to apply js only style, in this case for the modal-bg:

```
.js .modal-bg {display:none;}
```

and then you can remove the above js to hide the modal as it will be now in your css

[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myGVQK)

Comment: It seems to work I only need to check a small issue in chrome as when I reload the page the form is visible for just fraction of a second before going hidden.

Comment: that's it!! :) thanks .. this also fixed the issue with chrome too.  I will check on other browsers too just in case.

Comment: We missed out something important. For some reason the form goes hidden when you click on it. That means that we can't even sign up. :/ @pete

Comment: Sorry, that was me messing around with your jQuery, try the updated codepen now.  Or if you want to be able to click on the background to close the modal: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPLNdP

Comment: LOL  :)  ok ..... ps: the newer codepen with the "click on the background" feature is the best :) ...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a div with the id "signup", but that is the class name.

```
$(function() {
  $(".signup").hide();
});
```

Will hide the signup div when the page loads.

You could then use `$(".signup").toggle();` on the button click event.

If you combine these, e.g.

```
$(function() {
  $(".signup").hide();

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".signup").toggle();
  });
});
```

Then the button displays the signup block correctly, and it is hidden on page load.

Comment: I've already tried this. It does hide permanently the div class. So if I click on the button it doesn't show the form at all

Answer (score 1):

You hide the "signup" Div but try to restore the "modal" div

This works:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      $('#signup').css('display','block');
      $('.modal-bg').fadeIn();
});

    $('#close').click(function(){
          $('.modal-bg').fadeOut();     
          $('#signup').toggle();
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: @Ricky: Heres a fiddle with the code working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ccuxp3pn/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery to change the CSS on page load:

```
$('.signup').css({
  'display': 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First method (CSS) - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYMQxY)**

```
#signup {

     display: none;
}
```

**Second method (jQuery) - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myGVxx)**

```
$('#signup').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already figured it out in your codepen paste? That code is different from your post...

Anyway, you have 3 layers of divs in your Login dialog:
 #signup > modal-bg > modal

So if you want to hide #signup after loading the page:

```
$(function() {
  $("#signup").hide();
});
```

then you also need to show/hide #signup in your button events.

.modal-bg and #modal are child elements of #signup, so if you remain #signup in hidden, .modal-bg and #modal will always be hidden no matter what you do on them.

By the way, I suggest you to use FireBug or general developer tools (hit F12 in chrome/IE/FIrefox) to inspect HTML elements and check what goes wrong, at least that's how I found the problem in your code.

Comment: Yes I've found my answer but thanks for your comment. I will have all these as future reference for similar projects :)